# Subwoofer passive crossovers in series

Tags: audio

I have a passive crossover between my amp and subwoofer. However too much high frequency is coming through, I'd like it more subby.

If I were to add another passive crossover, so the wires going to the sub instead run into a second crossover module, would I be doubling the frequency rolloff?

#### Update with existing crossover

I have what is described as "600w RMS Subwoofer Crossover 4 Ohm 12dB/Oct" which are very common on eBay, around 13.00GBP.

I thought 120Hz was too high when I bought it - esp. after accounting for the rolloff - but there's nothing else on the market. Ideally it'd be variable like on many amps.

Indeed it sounds too mid-bassy, like for rock music, while I play house music with much deeper frequencies.

So I was wondering if I can simply add another! Else I'll need to buy something more expensive to augment on the signal side.

Thanks for comments.

Comment: Just add a larger inductor in series in the crossover.

Comment: If you can define passband width and stop band attenuation a better design might be possible. Otherwise if done wrong, you just have a bad design. This is because cascading LC filters is higher order yes but also can give rise to unwanted resonance.

Comment: Crossovers are custom tuned for a given speaker impedance. Those for 4 ohm speakers cannot be used for 8 ohm speakers, etc.

Comment: In other words Luke, you can try it, but the details prohibit a clear answer (and even whether it will sound better or like complete crud.)  There are a bazillion filter calculators out there, and [Crutchfield](https://www.crutchfield.com) sells all the parts you'd need to make a custom one.

Comment: A crossover filter is easy for me to design if you define what you got and what  you hear and don’t want to hear in an audio clip and speaker impedance and crossover model link

Comment: Thank you for your comments, all. I'm not an electrical engineer, I can solder and I know some basics, I just wanted to know if it was an immediately stupid idea.